# Apontado do Apontado C

Tags: c

Tenho uma duvida em relação a isto : `**ptr`

Consigo perceber todos os outros `(ptr++, &ptr, *ptr)`

Não sei qual será a melhor forma de perceber como funciona `**ptr` (Apontado do apontado.)

Obrigado a quem me conseguir esclarecer está duvida .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A parte importante para entender isso, é entender como ponteiros funcionam.

Vamos imaginar que declaramos um ponteiro com o conteúdo ABC:
    const char *c = "ABC";

Então, "ABC" está em algum lugar da memória e o ponteiro está também na memória. Se quisermos criar um ponteiro para c, também é possível com o código:

```
const char **cp = &c;
```

Nesse caso o ponteiro cp, também é alocado na memória e está apontando para onde está o ponteiro c.

Por exemplo, se tivermos olhando para um trecho de memória:

```
Endereço
21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30
-----------------------------------------------
 A |  B |  C |    | 21 |    | 25 |    |    |
Conteúdo

cp está no endereço 27 e aponta para o endereço 25.
c está no endereço 25 e aponta para o endereço 21.
no endereço 21, temos a string ABC.
```

Answer (score 3):

Imagina que tens vários apontadores para textos

```
char *lang_pt[] = {"rato", "teclado", "monitor"};
char *lang_en[] = {"mouse", "keyboard", "screen"};
```

e queres fazer um apontador único que aponte para a lingua que o utilizador escolheu

```
char **lang_user;
if (rand() % 2) lang_user = lang_pt;
else            lang_user = lang_en;

printf("2. %s\n", lang_user[1]); // teclado???? keyboard???
```

Answer (score 2):

Citando o Stack Overflow (em inglês):

- lista de caracteres (uma palavra): char *palavra;
- frase (uma lista de palavras): char **frase;
- monólogo (lista de frases): char ***monologo;

E por aí vai...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580761/why-use-double-pointer-or-why-use-pointers-to-pointers

Comment: +1, mas faltou um `*` no seu *monólogo*.